# how to include bump sdk but have it start disabled

Tags: android, bump

Using the sample app provided in the android download, I would like to use api.disableBumping() in the onCreate() method to add the broadcastreceiver but disablebumping until further notice. Application keeps  crashing on me.

Any pointers?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bindService(new Intent(IBumpAPI.class.getName()),
                connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CHANNEL_CONFIRMED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.DATA_RECEIVED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.NOT_MATCHED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.MATCHED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    try {
        api.disableBumping();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

debug info

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1816    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1837 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 132   
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1033  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 143 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4196    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Allow the crash to proceed in Eclipse, then look at LogCat to get the actual stack trace of the code that raised the original exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lines below I'm explaining how the logic of Bump works,

When calling

```
bindService(new Intent(IBumpAPI.class.getName()), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

the onServiceConnected gets called, which then you can call

```
    api = IBumpAPI.Stub.asInterface(binder);

    try  { api.configure("YOUR_API_KEY", "Bump User"); }
    catch (RemoteException e)  { }
```

Then you wait till the broadcast **CONNECTED** is received, from that point and onwards it's up to you when to call the api.enableBumping() or api.disableBumping()

Note: If your connection is down when calling the api.configure() a remote exception will be thrown.